# Parsing time for a large XML document in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, fork

I have a large XML file containing around 1.5 million lines.
The basic skeleton of the file is

```
<org>
   <dept>
      <emp> ... </emp>
      <emp> ... </emp>
      ...
   </dept>
</org>
```

Each `<emp>` node can even have upto .8 million lines

I am required to parse and hold the entire data in a hash.

I have tried using [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple) (I'm not allowed to use other modules like `XML::Twig` or `XML::libXML`).

The problem is that it takes around 5.5 minutes to parse the entire file. I need to bring it down to the order of 30 seconds.

I tried splitting it into multiple files, each containing one `<emp> .. </emp>` section. For example, I got around 100 files.

Then I used `fork` and used 100 child processes to parse each of these files.

I reduced the total time to around 1.5 minutes, but I am yet to find some means to communicate the data back from the child processes to the parent process.

Comment: I had to do that once with `XML` fastest way by far was using [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0115/LibXML.pod), it is `CPAN` but one of those modules that may or should already be installed due to dependencies.

Comment: What is *" upto .8 million lines"*? Do you mean "less than 800,000 lines"?

Comment: Please explain *"I am required to parse and hold the entire data in hash ref"*. That's a very specific requirement, and almost certainly unnecessary

Comment: Yes..I meant each `<emp>` node can contain around 800,000 lines.

Comment: The entire XML data is going to be used at various places down the line-onDemand basis.The entire data needs to reside in memory.So,hashref seems to be the best option.

Comment: The layout of you your question was dreadful. I have done my best to make it describe what I think you want, but you need to check it. Please don't use HTML tags in your posts: this site uses [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

Comment: There is no reason to keep everything that may be accessed in memory. Google, for instance, comes back with my query for `Chosera stone` within a quarter of a second, and I am certain that it doesn't keep an index of all of the internet in memory. Whoever has instructed you to aim for 30 seonds should be shot, as you are aiming for a ridiculous ideal that I doubt can be attained

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to use [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) which is designed for a purpose like this. It allows you to declare callback subroutines that are called when the prescribed XML elements are closed, and doesn't try to read the complete structure into memory.

Without a proper sample of your data I can't help any further, but it looks like you would declare a callback for the `dept` and the `emp` elements.

Comment: Thanks.But I am not supposed to use CPAN modules - instead I was advised to write own parser specific to this requirement if necessary.

Comment: @Soumya: What on earth are your employers thinking, and what do you mean by *"not supposed to use CPAN modules"*? You won't get far without `strict` and `warnings`. There are only a few modules on CPAN that will parse XML properly and have been tested thoroughly by the community. It takes a *lot* of work over several years to code something that is reliable and useable. And you are supposed to write something yourself on your own? I would quote them two years with a team of five, or perhaps offer them `XML::Twig` and its dependencies and say you wrote it yourself

Comment: @Soumya: Remember that the CPAN modules use XS, which is Perl's intermediate language that allows critical pieces of code to be written in C. You don't stand a chance of making your code run faster unless you get into writing XS modules yourself, and it's far from simple